# I need to auto generate bar codes that when a certain quantity is inputted in a `TextBox`

Tags: java, mysql, barcode

I need to auto generate bar codes that when a certain quantity is input in a `TextBox`.

FOR EXAMPLE:
the max value of `ProductID` in the database is `10000018`. When I input `2` in the `TextBox` it will generate bar code images with the value `10000019`, `10000020`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.aspose.barcode.BarCodeBuilder;
import com.aspose.barcode.Symbology;
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder;

String strBaseFolder = "C:\\users\\ronjonathan\\desktop\\barcode\\";

String query = "Select MAX(ProductID) from tblindividualproduct";
try
{
    int i=0;
    // Generate barcode image
    BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();
    builder.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Code128);

    pst=con.prepareStatement(query);    
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        for(i=rs.getInt(1); i<=Integer.parseInt(txtBarcode.getText()); i++){
            builder.setCodeText(Integer.toString(i));
            String strBarCodeImageSave = ""+i+".jpg";
            builder.save(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);
```

Comment: Your question is really hard to interpret, please elaborate.

Comment: sir what part did you not understand?

Comment: You don't have complete english sentences or an actual question

Comment: I tried to edit this post but it's still too hard to interpret.

Comment: my problem was already solved by Sabuh Hassan.

Comment: Happy to hear that, but please consider the future reviewers may take advantage or your question too.

Comment: im fixing it right now. i know it's kinda hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
if(rs.next()){
    int MAX = rs.getInt(1);
    for(i=1; i <= Integer.parseInt(txtBarcode.getText()); i++){
        ...
        String strBarCodeImageSave = ""+(i+MAX)+".jpg";
        ...
    }
}
```